# How do I set proxy for lynx

Tags: linux, perl, proxy, lynx

I am trying to run lynx in my perl cgi script so it extracts some text from wen page. I am doing it as in the following manner in my script,

`lynx -source -preparsed "$url" > data.txt`

But I get the following error in my server's error_log:

> Looking up www.xyz.com
>
> Making HTTP connection to www.xyz.com Alert!:
>
> Unable to connect to remote host.
>
> lynx: Can't access startfile xyz.com

I get the same error when I tried to execute lynx from the command line for root user. But the perl script and the lynx command work normally when I run it in normal user.Our newtwork consists of proxy settings which I had done in `/etc/lynx-site.cfg` as `PROTOCOL_proxy="http://proxy.abcdxyz.ac.in:8080"`.But it hasnot given any result.

Comment: What does the `lynx` manpage say?

Comment: the line protocol_proxy thats where I found it

Comment: Why are you shelling out to lynx instead of using LWP?

Comment: Using Lynx for this is a really bad idea. You should use LWP instead (or, at least HTTP::Tiny which has been included with Perl since 2011).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set a Lynx proxy as follows:

1. Edit `/etc/lynx-site.cfg`
2. Add:

   ```
   http_proxy:http://proxy.abc.xyz:8080
   ```

The proxy is set.